# Insert Linkedlist and Node

Tags: java

I'm working on insert method and my method is go through list and insert the item.therefore, i used if and else: if it's on first it will add on first, and else if (if its in middle) and else if(if its in the last.. I did for if it's first but i couldn't do if its middle and last! can someone help me if its middle and if its last?

```
public Node helpinsert(Node n)
{
    Node current = first;
    Node pre=null;

    while(current!=null && current.next!=null)
    {
        if(current.compareTo(n)<0){
            break;
        } else {
            pre=current;
            current=current.next;
        }
    }

     //if current is on first  
    if(current==first){
        n.next=current;
        first=n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a Node in middle,
 - First you have to find the index element.
 - Point new element's next to searched element's next.
 - Point the searched element's next to new element.

```
if(current != first && current != last){ //searched element is current
    n.next = current.next; //Point new element's next to searched element's next.
    current.next = n; //Point the searched element's next to new element.
}
```

If you want to add a Node in last,
 - First you have to find the index element.
 - Point new element's next to null.
 - Point the searched element's next to new element.

```
if(current == last){ //searched element is current
        n.next = null; //Point new element's next to null.
        current.next = n; //Point the searched element's next to new element.
}
```